# How to use shell logical operators for If else case

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need some help to write a script for the following scenario.

The requirement is, based on the number of configuration files`(*.cfg)` inside a given directory, I need load all the configuration file names with out the file extension into an array. If there is only one configuration file in the directory, then array will be assigned the value `""` (not the name of the only available configuration file)

I am trying to do this using logical operators. This is what i have tried so far.

```
[`ls *.cfg |wc -l`] || code_to_initialize_array;
```

My problem here is that, how do I integrate the case where i have only one configuration file.

Comment: & [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short code:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(*.cfg)
array=("${array[@]%.cfg}")
[ ${#array[@]} -eq 1 ] && array=""
```

Comment: If you have `set -e`, change last line to `[ ${#array[@]} -gt 1 ] || array=""`, to avoid shell from exitting.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

config=(*.cfg) #glob instead ls usage
num=${#config[@]}

case $num in
0)
echo "No config file"
;;
1)
echo "Only one config file"
;;
*)
code_to_initialize_array
;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have this example script for your requirement. It's detailed and variable names are long but you could have your own customizations. Using `readarray` is safer than `A=($(...))` since it doesn't depend on `IFS` and is not subject to pathname expansion.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=/path/to/somewhere

readarray -t FILES < <(compgen -G "${DIR%/}/*.cfg")  ## Store matches to array.
FILES_COUNT=${#FILES[@]}                             ## Match count.
FILES_NAMES=("${FILES[@]##*/}")                      ## No directory parts.
FILES_NAMES_WITHOUT_CFG=("${FILES_NAMES[@]%.cfg}")   ## No .cfg extension.

if [[ FILES_COUNT -gt 0 ]]; then
    printf "File: %s\n" "${FILES[@]}"
    printf "Name: %s\n" "${FILES_NAMES[@]}"
    printf "Name (no .cfg): %s\n" "${FILES_NAMES_WITHOUT_CFG[@]}"
    printf "Total: %d\n" "$FILES_COUNT"
fi
```

Note that each entry has the same index number. So `${FILES[1]}` is `${FILES_NAMES[1]}` and also `${FILES_NAMES_WITHOUT_CFG[1]}`. Entries begin with index `0`.

You can also have other details through this:

```
if [[ FILES_COUNT -gt 0 ]]; then
    for I in "${!FILES[@]}"; do
        printf "File: %s\n" "${FILES[I]}"
        printf "Name: %s\n" "${FILES_NAMES[I]}"
        printf "Name (no .sh): %s\n" "${FILES_NAMES_WITHOUT_CFG[I]}"
        printf "Index number: $I\n\n"
    done
    printf "Total: %d\n" "$FILES_COUNT"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked abusing a `for` loop for a situation like this.

```
for x in *.cfg; do
    [[ -f $x ]] && code_to_initialize_array
    break
```

The explicit `break` means the loop iterates only once, no matter how many `.cfg` files you have. If you have none, `*.cfg` will be treated literally, so the `[[ -f $x ]]` checks if the "first" `cfg` file actually exists before trying to run `code_to_initialize_array`.

Comment: This is so... `batch` file style code... (In batch files, there is no direct provision for `$()` type code. You need to write a loop usually with an un-conditional break.)

Comment: It's not pretty, but it is guaranteed to work for all config files, even weird ones whose names contain newlines. Such files will break any approach that relies on parsing the output of `ls`. This will also work (well, if you use `[ -f "$x" ]` instead) with any POSIX shell, which does not support the use of arrays.

Comment: Since the OP has a code to initialize the array, I assumed that the use of array is supported. :)